# unable to setState inside of useEffect for fetch callback

Tags: reactjs

I am attempting to get information from my node api to my react frontend but when I try to set the state inside of the useEffect hook I am getting an error that claims my "setData" function is not a function.

I followed the first section of this: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/fetch-data-react/

the console.log prints the data so I know the fetch is working correctly.

````
const CategorySelectionContainer = () => {

  const {data, setData} = useState([]);

  useEffect(()=>{
    fetch('/api/')
    .then(response => {
      if(response.ok) {
        return response.json()
      }
    })
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
      setData(data);
    })
  }, [])
  return <p>something</p>
};

export default CategorySelectionContainer```
````

Comment: please use useState hooks with squire bracket const [data, setData] = useState([]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`useState` returns a tuple and you're destructuring it as if it was an object.

`const [data, setData] = useState([]);` should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

`useState` should be used like this:

```
const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);
```

Or in your particular case:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
```

You can get more information by [this link](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate).